# Doxygen as documentation processor

Tags: doxygen

Is it possible to disable all code inspection features of Doxygen?

I mean: remove all class/function/variable/etc. Doxygen gathers parsing the sources while keeping all documentation explicitly marked as such (`\page`, `\subpage`, `\section`, `\subsection`, etc.), i.e.: everything going to `\mainpage` and friends and nothing going to "Namespaces", "Classes" and "Files".

Ideally this selection should be done at `Doxyfile` level, not editing the sources.

Reason behind this request is I use Doxygen to generate my documentation (of course!) and I would like to produce something like an "Executive Summary" where I explain what the various modules are supposed to do without bothering with actual API (let alone HOW it is done).

I am currently doing this just cutting the `.pdf` I produce, but that is really ugly as index is complete and it's plain a lot of material is simply missing (I managed to trim that out, but doing it manually is "sub-optimal").

Note: I **did** read all `Doxyfile` generated by `doxygen -g` but I didn't find anything useful; onlythimhs margimally useful were: `ALPHABETICAL_INDEX = NO` and `LATEX_HIDE_INDICES = YES`.

**UPDATE:** Following @albert advice (THANKS!) I tried messing with `LAYOUT_FILE`, but I was unable to make it work (which is a shame because it seems *exactly* what I need.

My current attempt is:

```
<doxygenlayout version="1.0">
  <!-- Generated by doxygen 1.9.5 -->
  <!-- Navigation index tabs for HTML output -->
  <navindex>
    <tab type="mainpage" visible="yes" title=""/>
    <tab type="pages" visible="yes" title="" intro=""/>
    <tab type="modules" visible="no" title="" intro=""/>
    <tab type="namespaces" visible="no" title="">
      <tab type="namespacelist" visible="no" title="" intro=""/>
      <tab type="namespacemembers" visible="no" title="" intro=""/>
    </tab>
    <tab type="concepts" visible="no" title="">
    </tab>
    <tab type="interfaces" visible="no" title="">
      <tab type="interfacelist" visible="no" title="" intro=""/>
      <tab type="interfaceindex" visible="no" title=""/>
      <tab type="interfacehierarchy" visible="no" title="" intro=""/>
    </tab>
    <tab type="classes" visible="no" title="">
      <tab type="classlist" visible="no" title="" intro=""/>
      <tab type="classindex" visible="no" title=""/>
      <tab type="hierarchy" visible="no" title="" intro=""/>
      <tab type="classmembers" visible="no" title="" intro=""/>
    </tab>
    <tab type="structs" visible="no" title="">
      <tab type="structlist" visible="no" title="" intro=""/>
      <tab type="structindex" visible="no" title=""/>
    </tab>
    <tab type="exceptions" visible="no" title="">
      <tab type="exceptionlist" visible="no" title="" intro=""/>
      <tab type="exceptionindex" visible="no" title=""/>
      <tab type="exceptionhierarchy" visible="no" title="" intro=""/>
    </tab>
    <tab type="files" visible="no" title="">
      <tab type="filelist" visible="no" title="" intro=""/>
      <tab type="globals" visible="no" title="" intro=""/>
    </tab>
    <tab type="examples" visible="no" title="" intro=""/>
  </navindex>

  <!-- Layout definition for a class page -->
  <class visible="no">
    <briefdescription visible="no"/>
    <includes visible="no"/>
    <inheritancegraph visible="no"/>
    <collaborationgraph visible="no"/>
    <memberdecl>
      <nestedclasses visible="no" title=""/>
      <publictypes title=""/>
      <services title=""/>
      <interfaces title=""/>
      <publicslots title=""/>
      <signals title=""/>
      <publicmethods title=""/>
      <publicstaticmethods title=""/>
      <publicattributes title=""/>
      <publicstaticattributes title=""/>
      <protectedtypes title=""/>
      <protectedslots title=""/>
      <protectedmethods title=""/>
      <protectedstaticmethods title=""/>
      <protectedattributes title=""/>
      <protectedstaticattributes title=""/>
      <packagetypes title=""/>
      <packagemethods title=""/>
      <packagestaticmethods title=""/>
      <packageattributes title=""/>
      <packagestaticattributes title=""/>
      <properties title=""/>
      <events title=""/>
      <privatetypes title=""/>
      <privateslots title=""/>
      <privatemethods title=""/>
      <privatestaticmethods title=""/>
      <privateattributes title=""/>
      <privatestaticattributes title=""/>
      <friends title=""/>
      <related title="" subtitle=""/>
      <membergroups visible="no"/>
    </memberdecl>
    <detaileddescription title=""/>
    <memberdef>
      <inlineclasses title=""/>
      <typedefs title=""/>
      <enums title=""/>
      <services title=""/>
      <interfaces title=""/>
      <constructors title=""/>
      <functions title=""/>
      <related title=""/>
      <variables title=""/>
      <properties title=""/>
      <events title=""/>
    </memberdef>
    <allmemberslink visible="no"/>
    <usedfiles visible="no"/>
    <authorsection visible="no"/>
  </class>

  <!-- Layout definition for a namespace page -->
  <namespace visible="no">
    <briefdescription visible="no"/>
    <memberdecl>
      <nestednamespaces visible="no" title=""/>
      <constantgroups visible="no" title=""/>
      <interfaces visible="no" title=""/>
      <classes visible="no" title=""/>
      <concepts visible="no" title=""/>
      <structs visible="no" title=""/>
      <exceptions visible="no" title=""/>
      <typedefs title=""/>
      <sequences title=""/>
      <dictionaries title=""/>
      <enums title=""/>
      <functions title=""/>
      <variables title=""/>
      <membergroups visible="no"/>
    </memberdecl>
    <detaileddescription title=""/>
    <memberdef>
      <inlineclasses title=""/>
      <typedefs title=""/>
      <sequences title=""/>
      <dictionaries title=""/>
      <enums title=""/>
      <functions title=""/>
      <variables title=""/>
    </memberdef>
    <authorsection visible="no"/>
  </namespace>

  <!-- Layout definition for a concept page -->
  <concept visible="no">
    <briefdescription visible="no"/>
    <includes visible="no"/>
    <definition visible="no" title=""/>
    <detaileddescription title=""/>
    <authorsection visible="no"/>
  </concept>

  <!-- Layout definition for a file page -->
  <file visible="no">
    <briefdescription visible="no"/>
    <includes visible="no"/>
    <includegraph visible="no"/>
    <includedbygraph visible="no"/>
    <sourcelink visible="no"/>
    <memberdecl>
      <interfaces visible="no" title=""/>
      <classes visible="no" title=""/>
      <structs visible="no" title=""/>
      <exceptions visible="no" title=""/>
      <namespaces visible="no" title=""/>
      <concepts visible="no" title=""/>
      <constantgroups visible="no" title=""/>
      <defines title=""/>
      <typedefs title=""/>
      <sequences title=""/>
      <dictionaries title=""/>
      <enums title=""/>
      <functions title=""/>
      <variables title=""/>
      <membergroups visible="no"/>
    </memberdecl>
    <detaileddescription title=""/>
    <memberdef>
      <inlineclasses title=""/>
      <defines title=""/>
      <typedefs title=""/>
      <sequences title=""/>
      <dictionaries title=""/>
      <enums title=""/>
      <functions title=""/>
      <variables title=""/>
    </memberdef>
    <authorsection/>
  </file>

  <!-- Layout definition for a group page -->
  <group visible="no">
    <briefdescription visible="no"/>
    <groupgraph visible="no"/>
    <memberdecl>
      <nestedgroups visible="no" title=""/>
      <dirs visible="no" title=""/>
      <files visible="no" title=""/>
      <namespaces visible="no" title=""/>
      <concepts visible="no" title=""/>
      <classes visible="no" title=""/>
      <defines title=""/>
      <typedefs title=""/>
      <sequences title=""/>
      <dictionaries title=""/>
      <enums title=""/>
      <enumvalues title=""/>
      <functions title=""/>
      <variables title=""/>
      <signals title=""/>
      <publicslots title=""/>
      <protectedslots title=""/>
      <privateslots title=""/>
      <events title=""/>
      <properties title=""/>
      <friends title=""/>
      <membergroups visible="no"/>
    </memberdecl>
    <detaileddescription title=""/>
    <memberdef>
      <pagedocs/>
      <inlineclasses title=""/>
      <defines title=""/>
      <typedefs title=""/>
      <sequences title=""/>
      <dictionaries title=""/>
      <enums title=""/>
      <enumvalues title=""/>
      <functions title=""/>
      <variables title=""/>
      <signals title=""/>
      <publicslots title=""/>
      <protectedslots title=""/>
      <privateslots title=""/>
      <events title=""/>
      <properties title=""/>
      <friends title=""/>
    </memberdef>
    <authorsection visible="no"/>
  </group>

  <!-- Layout definition for a directory page -->
  <directory visible="no">
    <briefdescription visible="no"/>
    <directorygraph visible="no"/>
    <memberdecl>
      <dirs visible="no"/>
      <files visible="no"/>
    </memberdecl>
    <detaileddescription title=""/>
  </directory>
</doxygenlayout>
```

where almost all `visible` attributes are set to "no".

Unfortunately the only place where this is honored is in `<navindex>` (which confirms layout file is actually used). Output is otherwise unchanged.

Specifically `LaTeX` output is complete and "very similar" to plain output.

I also tried to set a `visibility="no"` on `<class>` but it also has no effect.

Most likely I'm missing something, but I cannot divine what.

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using?   Maybe you should have a look at the layout possibilities, see a.o. https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/customize.html#layout

Comment: @albert: I update O.P. What am I missing?

Comment: I think that the proposed pull request https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/pull/9290 might give some extra possibilities. I cannot test it at the moment as I don't have a good testing environment at hand.

Answer (score 0):

I had partial success using the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
set +e

cat > tmp.doxyfile <<EOF
PROJECT_NAME           = "My Awesome Project"
QUIET                  = YES
EXTRACT_ALL            = YES
EXTRACT_STATIC         = YES
JAVADOC_AUTOBRIEF      = YES
RECURSIVE              = YES
INPUT                  = ../src/
EXAMPLE_PATH           = ../src/
PLANTUML_JAR_PATH      = /usr/local/bin/plantuml.jar

PROJECT_NUMBER = "version in git: $(git describe --always --dirty --long)"

ALPHABETICAL_INDEX     = NO
LATEX_HIDE_INDICES     = YES
UML_LOOK               = YES
EXTRACT_LOCAL_CLASSES  = YES
SHOW_HEADERFILE        = NO
VERBATIM_HEADERS       = NO
FULL_PATH_NAMES        = NO

GENERATE_HTML          = NO

LAYOUT_FILE            = tmp.layout.xml
EOF

cat > tmp.layout.xml <<EOF
<doxygenlayout version="1.0">
  <!-- Generated by doxygen 1.9.5 -->
  <!-- Navigation index tabs for HTML output -->
  <navindex>
    <tab type="mainpage" visible="yes" title=""/>
    <tab type="pages" visible="yes" title="" intro=""/>
  </navindex>

  <!-- Layout definition for a class page -->
  <class visible="no">
    <briefdescription visible="yes"/>
  </class>

  <!-- Layout definition for a namespace page -->
  <namespace visible="no">
    <briefdescription visible="yes"/>
  </namespace>

  <!-- Layout definition for a concept page -->
  <concept visible="no">
    <briefdescription visible="yes"/>
  </concept>

  <!-- Layout definition for a file page -->
  <file visible="no">
    <briefdescription visible="yes"/>
  </file>

  <!-- Layout definition for a group page -->
  <group visible="no">
    <briefdescription visible="yes"/>
  </group>

  <!-- Layout definition for a directory page -->
  <directory visible="no">
    <briefdescription visible="yes"/>
  </directory>
</doxygenlayout>
EOF
rm -r html latex
doxygen tmp.doxyfile
rm tmp.doxyfile tmp.layout.xml
cat > tmp.doxyfile <<EOF
PROJECT_NAME           = "My Awesome Project"
QUIET                  = YES
EXTRACT_ALL            = YES
EXTRACT_STATIC         = YES
JAVADOC_AUTOBRIEF      = YES
RECURSIVE              = YES
INPUT                  = ../src/
EXAMPLE_PATH           = ../src/
CALL_GRAPH             = YES
PLANTUML_JAR_PATH      = /usr/local/bin/plantuml.jar

DISABLE_INDEX          = YES
GENERATE_TREEVIEW      = YES
GENERATE_LATEX         = NO

PROJECT_NUMBER = "version in git: $(git describe --always --dirty --long)"
EOF
doxygen tmp.doxyfile
rm tmp.doxyfile
[ -f doc.zip ] && rm doc.zip
( cd latex && make )>/dev/null && zip -rq doc.zip latex/refman.pdf html/
```

This creates a "full fledged" HTML version and an "executive summary" LaTeX version. This is acceptable but still unsatisfactory for two reasons:

1. I am "hiding" sections by deleting them and this is "not recommended" in Doxygen manual... OTOH I found way to have `visible` attribute to work for me.
2. I still have to keep at least `<briefdescription visible="yes"/>` in all sections because otherwise defaults would kick in.

I will not accept my own answer for a few days in hope someone could come up with a better solution.